# Helm template for Vault annotation

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I'm trying to nest one template into another, namely I have a k8s deployment.yaml which should be templated by helm. However, it is already using Vault template in annotation field responsible for injecting secrets into the pod.

Without Helm template it looks like this:

```
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-.env: |
  {{- with secret (print "envs/data/test") -}}{{- range $k, $v := .Data.data -}}
  {{ $k }}={{ $v }}
  {{ end }}{{- end -}}
```

Now, I would like to make a template for Helm and replace path `envs/data/test` with value coming from Helm values. So I've tried to use it like that:

```
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-.env: |
  {{- with secret (print {{ .Values.path }}) -}}{{- range $k, $v := .Data.data -}}
  {{ $k }}={{ $v }}
  {{ end }}{{- end -}}
```

This however does not work meaning `{{ .Values.path }}` is outputed as is, as a string.
How can I template over another template and resolve `{{ .Values.path }}` as a variable?

Answer (score 0):

It means you put template over template, and helm and vault use same semantics, and it will replace your vault template.

So you need another approach, like putting vault template manually inside configmap for vault or use [vswh from banzai](https://banzaicloud.com/docs/bank-vaults/mutating-webhook/) it will help you inject into pod automatically by mutating your application, and you need put your secret as ENV as vswh format in your deployment/template deployment file.